# how to use a variable to store the amount of an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using (#userGuess").val() for each statement but would like to have a variable called userGuess that pulls the input value for #userGuess so I can use it to compare. The goal of this project is to create an app that tells you whether you are guess is hot or cold based on the randomly generated number. Here is what I have so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/pLnch91t/

```
var randomNumber = 0;
var guessCount = 0;
var userGuess = 0;   
var win = false;
//user guess
function compareGuess(){  
    if ($("#userGuess").val() == randomNumber) {
        changeFeedback('You Win!');
        win = true;
    } else if ($("#userGuess").val() > randomNumber+50){
        changeFeedback('You are very cold');
    } else if ($("#userGuess").val() < randomNumber+50){
        changeFeedback('You are very cold');
    } else if ($("#userGuess").val() > randomNumber+30 &&  $("#userGuess").val() <= randomNumber+50){
        changeFeedback('You are cold');
    } else if ($("#userGuess").val() < randomNumber+30 && $("#userGuess").val() >= randomNumber+50){
        changeFeedback('You are cold');
    } else if ($("#userGuess").val() > randomNumber+20 && $("#userGuess").val() <= randomNumber+30){
        changeFeedback('You are warm');
    } else if ($("#userGuess").val() < randomNumber+20 && $("#userGuess").val() >= randomNumber+30){
        changeFeedback('You are warm');
    } else if ($("#userGuess").val() > randomNumber+10 && $("#userGuess").val() <= randomNumber+20){
        changeFeedback('You are hot');
    } else if ($("#userGuess").val() < randomNumber+10 && $("#userGuess").val() >= randomNumber+20){
        changeFeedback('You are hot');
    } else if ($("#userGuess").val() >= randomNumber+1 &&         $("#userGuess").val() <= randomNumber+10){
    changeFeedback('You are very hot');
    } else if ($("#userGuess").val() <= randomNumber+1 &&         $("#userGuess").val() >= randomNumber+10){
        changeFeedback('You are very hot');
    }
}

    <section class="game"> <!-- Guessing Section -->

        <h2 id="feedback">Make your Guess!</h2>

        <form>
            <input type="text" name="userGuess" id="userGuess" class="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your Guess" required/>
            <input type="submit" id="guessButton" class="button" name="submit" value="Guess"/>
        </form>

        <p>Guess #<span id="count">0</span>!</p>

        <ul id="guessList" class="guessBox clearfix">

        </ul>

    </section>
```

Comment: `userGuess = $("#userGuess").val();`? :) Certainly save on a lot of duplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this do it for you?

```
var randomNumber = 0;
var guessCount = 0;
var userGuess = 0;   
var win = false;
//user guess
function compareGuess(){  
    userGuess = $("#userGuess").val();
    if (userGuess == randomNumber) {
        changeFeedback('You Win!');
        win = true;
    } else if (userGuess > randomNumber+50){
        changeFeedback('You are very cold');
    } else if (userGuess < randomNumber+50){
        changeFeedback('You are very cold');
    } else if (userGuess > randomNumber+30 &&  userGuess <= randomNumber+50){
        changeFeedback('You are cold');
    } else if (userGuess < randomNumber+30 && userGuess >= randomNumber+50){
        changeFeedback('You are cold');
    } else if (userGuess > randomNumber+20 && userGuess <= randomNumber+30){
        changeFeedback('You are warm');
    } else if (userGuess < randomNumber+20 && userGuess >= randomNumber+30){
        changeFeedback('You are warm');
    } else if (userGuess > randomNumber+10 && userGuess <= randomNumber+20){
        changeFeedback('You are hot');
    } else if (userGuess < randomNumber+10 && userGuess >= randomNumber+20){
        changeFeedback('You are hot');
    } else if (userGuess >= randomNumber+1 &&         userGuess <= randomNumber+10){
    changeFeedback('You are very hot');
    } else if (userGuess <= randomNumber+1 &&         userGuess >= randomNumber+10){
        changeFeedback('You are very hot');
    }
}

    <section class="game"> <!-- Guessing Section -->

        <h2 id="feedback">Make your Guess!</h2>

        <form>
            <input type="text" name="userGuess" id="userGuess" class="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your Guess" required/>
            <input type="submit" id="guessButton" class="button" name="submit" value="Guess"/>
        </form>

        <p>Guess #<span id="count">0</span>!</p>

        <ul id="guessList" class="guessBox clearfix">

        </ul>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you did not really ask for this, but the code is awfully inefficient.

What about this:

```
var difference = $("#userGuess").val() - randomNumber;
if(difference < 0)
    difference = -difference; // <- this will already safe half of the comparisons
if(difference == 0) { /*...*/ }
else if(difference > 50) { /*...*/ }
else if(difference > 30) { /*...*/ }
else if(difference > 20) { /*...*/ }
else if(difference > 10) { /*...*/ }
else { /*...*/ }
```

You can leave out the upper bound comparison (<=), as you checked already in the previous if! The >= 1 comparison is obsolete, as being the only cases left.

The assignment you asked for, btw. you get indirectly in the difference (I first subtracted the random number, however).